# Correct extra spaces in URL with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Can .htaccess be used to correct extra space errors in URL encoded links?

For example:

> Incorrect: **http://%20www.google.com/**
>
> Correct : **http://www.google.com/**

Comment: Not if the are in the domainname.

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\%20$ $1 [NC]
```

Something to that effect should work, don't count me on it.

Regex will help you.
http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php

If you have captured all your error pages, you could write something in the server language of your error page e.g. error.php and get that to do the string edit for you rather than rely on htaccess, as you may not want to really replace all spaces with nothing as files can have spaces in their name. String comparisons are expensive so may be best to only do it if there is an error, depends on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I have concluded that removing the leading space is not possible though .htaccess or error pages. Trying to access that page will return a Error 105 (Unable to resolve the server's DNS address). Therefore, .htaccess or a server error page will have no effect as the client cannot reach the server.